# Gradient descent with convex function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

there is someone that can give me the proof of the convergence of the gradient descent with a convex function or a reference to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to [lecture notes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F13/scribes/lec6.pdf) where the needed result is the first theorem discussed, assuming you are talking about fixed step size.